# Get actual value in Future Scala

Tags: scala

```
val result: Future[Option[String]] = //something
```

how can i get the string value from the above example. result contains string :

```
val memcached =  Memcached(Configuration("127.0.0.1:11211"))
import concurrent.duration._ // for specifying timeouts
import concurrent.Future
val op: Future[Unit] = memcached.set("username", "Alex", 1.minute)
val result: Future[Option[String]] = memcached.get[String]("username")
```

I want actual value from result.

Comment: Read the tin on `Future`, `Await` and so on, this is a very basic question that's best solved via reading documentation.